# Find all solutions of $z^5+a^5=0$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

The task is as follows:

Find all solutions of $z^5+a^5=0$, where $a$ is a positive real number.

---

### My initial attempt

*(which leads nowhere)*

My guess is that i'll have to find the 5 5th roots of $-z^5$:

$w_1 = |-z^5|^5(cos(\frac{\theta}{5})+isin(\frac{\theta}{5})) \\
w_1  = |z|(cos(\frac{\theta}{5})+isin(\frac{\theta}{5})$

Then, the other roots are:

$w_2  = |z|(cos(\frac{\theta+2\pi}{5})+isin(\frac{\theta+2\pi}{5}) \\
w_3  = |z|(cos(\frac{\theta+4\pi}{5})+isin(\frac{\theta+4\pi}{5}) \\
w_4  = |z|(cos(\frac{\theta+6\pi}{5})+isin(\frac{\theta+6\pi}{5}) \\
w_5  = |z|(cos(\frac{\theta+8\pi}{5})+isin(\frac{\theta+8\pi}{5})$

but i'm not sure what to do with this new information. Also, I guess $z^5$ have to be a negative real number, since added to $a^5$ its $0$. Again, not sure what to do with this either.

Comment: It would be easy to compute the roots of $z=(-1)^5a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out (delayed [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?)

I define $z=(r,\theta)$. Then $z^5=(r^5,5\theta)$.

Since $z^5$ have to be a real negative number,

$$ 5\theta=\pi+2\pi n \\ \theta=\frac{\pi+2\pi n}{5}$$ 
And since $$r^5=a^5 \\ r=a$$

Then $z=(a, \frac{\pi+2\pi n}{5})$.

Or, with a more straight forward notation:
$z=a(cos(\frac{\pi+2\pi n}{5})+i sin(\frac{\pi+2\pi n}{5}))$.

Answer (score 1):

To make our life a bit easier, start by writing $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ for some $r>0$ and some real $\theta,$ so that $$-a^5=z^5\\-a^5=r^5(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^5\\-a^5=r^5(\cos5\theta+i\sin5\theta)$$ Now, taking the modulus of both sides gives us $$a^5=r^5,$$ so we'll need $r=a,$ and so $z=a(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta).$ Moreover, since $$-a^5=r^5(\cos5\theta+i\sin5\theta)\\-a^5=a^5(\cos5\theta+i\sin5\theta),$$ then $$-1=\cos5\theta+i\sin5\theta,$$ meaning that we need $\theta$ such that $$-1=\cos5\theta\\0=\sin5\theta.$$ This is true if and only if $5\theta$ is an odd integer multiple of $\pi.$ Can you take it from there to find appropriate values of $\theta$ to give $5$ distinct solutions $z$?